# Disable hibernation on a specific partition

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, hibernate

After a long time googling I have not found an answer that works.

I have a shared partition that is mounted on Z: . When I manually unmount that partition using `mountvol Z: /p` in cmd, it doesn't get hibernated. I have tried to set up a batch script to execute that same command using the task scheduler. I set the trigger to system kernel power id 42. This doesn't seem to work as the partition gets hibernated. I also found [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd143253.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#hormdismountingvolumesbeforehibernation) but I have no idea how to use it to achieve what I want. I just want to automatically unmount/not hibernate a certain partition when I hibernate windows.

Any help is appreciated.